# Starting Three20 sample project in landscape mode renders half the screen unresponsive to touch events

Tags: iphone, three20

I am interested in developing a [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) based application for iPhone OS that is primarily landscape oriented.

I downloaded the Three20 [sample project templates](http://three20.info/setup/templates), loaded them in Xcode, and started the sample project app fine in the simulator and on the device using the 3.0, 3.1, 3.1.2 SDK.  When I changed the `Initial interface orientation` to `Landscape (right home button)` in the project's `Info.plist` file, the project started in that orientation as expected, but only responded to touch events on left-hand side of the screen.  It appears as if it is still responding to touch events as if it is still in portrait mode.  The *only* change I've made to the sample project is changing the `Info.plist` file.

Am I missing something very simple?  Starting in landscape orientation seems to be a very basic use case - but I can't find anyone else who's filed an issue report or blog post on it after googling around for a couple of days.

Note: This is a problem I encountered originally in a much more advanced project while introducing landscape orientation, but I backed up to the most basic repeatable example to rule out any other code as the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that all views have the correct `autoresizingMask`property set. As most views do not clip to bounds, content is also visible beyond the bounds of the parentView. Touches however are alway clipped to bounds, which could lead to childViews being visible out side of the bounds of the parentView, but not being touchable.

Ergo: if a parent view does not fit the new width, the right part of the screen might be rendered with content that is not touchable.

Comment: This sounds like it could be the problem, if not related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a specific view? It could be as simple as needing to add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

To your view controller.

Comment: I have this method implemented on my more complex instantiation of this problem, but I tested it on the simple one for good measure.  In neither case does it help the landscaped Three20 view register touch events on the right half of the screen.

Comment: That sounds weird. I don't have my Mac in front of me right now. Will take a look at it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
 if (![System isIpad])
 {
  if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
   ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
  {
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
  }
 }
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
// self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
// self.navigationBarTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:FALSE];
}
```